# Reset Flythrough mode?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Typically, I have no problems using Flythrough mode in Unity to navigate the viewport.  (More details at https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/SceneViewNavigation.html, but TL;DR, it's when you hold down the right mouse button and use WASD to move.)
I think I hit some key by accident and now W and S no longer work when I try to use Flythrough mode.  Is there some way to reset Flythrough mode so it works normally again?
(Note: I already tried restarting Unity, but that didn't work.)

Answer (score 3):

I found one solution.  I has to use "Reset All Views".

Comment: And in Unity 2022, that would be (at the top right) Click Default -> Reset All Layouts. Fixed the issue for me!

Answer (score 1):

I found that in the Edit menu, "Frame Selected" (select something and hit [F]) or "Lock View to Selected" [SHIFT]+F got me out of the same problem w/o having to reset views.
Unity version 2021.2.7f1